# How to achieve jpeg lossless?

Tags: java, image, jpeg, jai

How to achieve jpeg-lossess in Java?

```
ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("JPEG-LS").next();
ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
param.setCompressionType("JPEG-LS");
writer.setOutput(ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\RileyRen\\Desktop\\123.jpg")));
writer.write(null, new IIOImage(subBufferedImage, null, null), param);
```

Will throw an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown compression type!
    at javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam.setCompressionType(ImageWriteParam.java:1041)
    at com.demandforce.ImageCrop.main(ImageCrop.java:59)
```

The `param.getCompressionTypes()` only print `[JPEG]`.

using `JAI`(version 1.1.3):

```
    PlanarImage input = JAI.create("fileload", "C:\\Users\\RileyRen\\Desktop\\test.jpg");
    ParameterBlock pb = new ParameterBlock();
    pb.addSource(input);
    pb.add(x);
    pb.add(y);
    pb.add(width);
    pb.add(height);
    PlanarImage output = JAI.create("crop",pb,null);
    JAI.create("filestore",output,"C:\\Users\\RileyRen\\Desktop\\123.jpg","JPEG-LS");
```

Also throw exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FileStore The specified format has no associated registered ImageCodec.
    at javax.media.jai.JAI.createNS(JAI.java:1087)
    at javax.media.jai.JAI.create(JAI.java:973)
    at javax.media.jai.JAI.create(JAI.java:1621)
    at com.demandforce.ImageCrop.main(ImageCrop.java:103)
```

Can you write an sample please?

Comment: Try `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(param.getCompressionTypes()))`.

Comment: Strange. Can you print the class name of the ImageWriter for the first class? If you really have the CLibJPEGImageWriter from JAI (the only writer capable of JPEG-LS AFAIK), it should support both JPEG-LS and JPEG-LOSSLESS. Note: These are different algorithms, not synonyms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard java does not have a compression type for JPEG-LS.

You can to download and use the JAI (Java Advanced Imaging) API though which I beleive includes such a compression type.

Can be downloaded from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/current-142188.html)

Comment: Can you write a sample?thk u!

Comment: After installing JAI you should just be able to use your first implementation as it installed the new compression types. I think to do this it is actually the Java Advanced Imaging Image I/O Tools you want to download and install. Available also at this link

Comment: Before I run the first example, JAI was already installed.But I didn't try the Java Advanced Imaging Image I/O Tools.Hopes it will work.

Answer (score 1):

The first code snippet has a typo:

```
param.setCompressionType("JPEG-lS");
```

It has to be

```
param.setCompressionType("JPEG-LS");
```

(all upper case).
I think it is otherwise correct and should work.

To query possible types, use `param.getCompressionTypes()` (as noted in a comment).

Comment: I think it is not the problem,I had tried "JPEG-LS"、"JPEG-LOSSLESS",also throwed exceptions.thk u,anyway.The `param.getCompressionTypes()` only print `[JPEG]`.

Comment: Ok. You should probably edit the question, to avoid confusion. :)