# Converted byte array to image and back to byte array, the values changed

Tags: image, jpeg, bufferedimage, steganography

I tried to implement steganography with the following steps :
1. Converted image to buffered image
2. Converted buffered image to Bytes array
3. Made modifications in the byte array
4. Converted byte array back to buffered image
5. Saved it as a jpg file

The problem arose when i read the saved file again, converted it to byte array and found that byte array is different from what i obtained after Step 3. (although there were not much difference as 6 converted to 7, 9 to 8 and so on)

I really have no idea why did this happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am reading an image and changing it. But the changes are not being saved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562479/i-am-reading-an-image-and-changing-it-but-the-changes-are-not-being-saved)

Answer (score 1):

1. If you save as a JPEG, the RGB data gets converted to YCbCr. Those two color spaces have different gamuts so values get clamped.
2. JPEG data may be subsampled, causing data to be changed. You can avoid these changes by not subsampling.
3. The JPEG DCT may introduce small errors (limited to +/-1 if implemented correctly)
4. Quantization will make rather large changes to the data. You can avoid changes at this step by having all 1s in your quantization tables.

No matter what you do, #1 and #3 can introduce changes in the JPEG compression process.

Answer (score 0):

JPG is a lossy image format, so you can't expect it to hold the data exactly after it is saved. It is especially unsuited for steganography, as it will destroy the small details required for this use, even when using the highest quality setting.

Solution is to use a lossless format, like PNG.

Answer (score 0):

A BufferedImage may be already a byte array. If when you create you BufferedImage you use the encoding TYPE_BYTE_GRAY, 3BYTE_BGR or 4BYTE_ABGR, then your BufferedImage is already a byte array. To access the byte array, you do: `byte[] buffer = ((DataBufferByte)my image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData() ;`

And when you write an image as a JPEG, you compress with loss your image. So the information you save is altered and cannot be retrieved as before. You should use PNG/TIFF/BMP, PNG being the most common.