# Java Advanced Imaging error while doing jpeg lossless compression

Tags: java

I want to do jpeg lossless compression while uploading file, this is testing code I have written, am not able to execute it (run time error), attached exception code, did I iss anything

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("E:\\pics\\Original\\testCompress\\bouncy-crayon-playland-2.JPG");
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(inputStream);                        
            JPEGImageWriter writer = (JPEGImageWriter) ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("JPEG-LS").next();       
            ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
            param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
            param.setCompressionType("JPEG-LS");        
            writer.setOutput(ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(new File("E:\\pics\\Original\\testCompress\\bouncy-crayon-playland-2-compressed.JPG")));       
            writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);
```

It's giving error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
            at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.next(Unknown Source)
            at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageWriterIterator.next(Unknown Source)
            at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageWriterIterator.next(Unknown Source)
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is due to Standard Java doesn't support JPEG-LS. When your code executes:

```
ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("JPEG-LS").next();
```

It looks for existing "ImageWriters" that handle the JPEG-LS format, but there's none, so you are warned with NoSuchElementException.

If you want to compress images in JPEG-LS, check this thread: [How to achieve jpeg lossless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187880/how-to-achieve-jpeg-lossless)

However, I've changed your code in order to get it work.

```
InputStream inputStream;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream("E:\\pics\\Original\\testCompress\\bouncy-crayon-playland-2.JPG");
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(inputStream);              
            ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg").next();      
            ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
            param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
            param.setCompressionQuality(1);      
            writer.setOutput(ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(new File("E:\\pics\\Original\\testCompress\\bouncy-crayon-playland-2-compressed.JPG")));       
            writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This code doesn't compress in JPEG-LS, but it reduces the size of the image (theoretically loses the minimum of quality) using:

```
param.setCompressionQuality(1);
```

Hope this helps.