# How to work with JPEG-LS in Java

Tags: java, jpeg

Is there any example how to work with `JPEG-LS` in java?
Some library?

Comment: Where do you need it for?

Comment: I work with `jpg` image and i need to save same RGB pixel color which i create in java program.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17188394/461499

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have heard this might work:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/current-142188.html

However, there is extremely little support for JPEG-LS. It is effectively an orphan format.